# how does solana communicate with Arweave ? how does solana pay its fee to ar?

Tags: data-storage

I hear that solana use Arweave to store some history data.
In that case, almost every Solana transaction (every Solana transaction that touches any state older than 2 days) causes a Solana network validator to request and receive data from an Arweave node in order to build the block, correct? Does this mean that Solana's validator software contains in its code a client implementation for the Arweave protocol? Does it mean that in any given second, Solana validators are requesting a continuous stream of data from Arweave nodes as new Solana transactions come in?

Do you happen to know how Solana pays its fees to Arweave? Does it get deducted from network transaction fees, or is there an additional block subsidy to pay Arweave for storage? Is there any way to check to see how much the Solana network is currently paying to store its history with Arweave?

It seems like this integration tightly couples Solana to Arweave, so anyone who is bullish on Solana usage should also be bullish on the Arweave "AR" token for as long as Solana is paying to archive so much data to Arweave, right?

Answer (score 3):

Solana doesn't have any tie to Arweave.

Many users optionally upload files to Arweave that are used for Solana NFTs. Metaplex NFTs (the standard for Solana NFTs) allow users to post an external URI to host metadata and files associated with NFT. Metaplex has a good resource on this [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview).

There are a couple of tools that make it possible to pay Arweave fees with Solana, most notably [Bundlr](https://docs.bundlr.network/learn/bundlr-arweave) and the [Metaplex JS SDK](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js) (which uses Bundlr under the hood).

A popular alternative on Solana for decentralized file storage is [Shadow Drive](https://docs.genesysgo.com/shadow/). Users can create accounts and buy storage with $SHDW (an SPL token on Solana) and $SOL (for tx fees), so all you need is a Solana wallet.

Comment: so the full nodes just store all the history data? the data will increase 4pb per year, is there a way to clean some old data?